# Missing Implicit for Log Cats.Effect.IO

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I am trying to get this simple example running using the redis4cats library:

```scala
import cats.effect._
import cats.implicits._
import dev.profunktor.redis4cats.Redis
import dev.profunktor.redis4cats.effect.Log.noop

object QuickStart extends IOApp {

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    Redis[IO].utf8("redis://localhost").use { cmd =>
      for {
        _ <- cmd.set("foo", "123")
        x <- cmd.get("foo")
        _ <- cmd.setNx("foo", "should not happen")
        y <- cmd.get("foo")
        _ <- IO(println(x === y)) // true
      } yield ExitCode.Success
    }

}
```

I have put in my build definition the follows:

libraryDependencies += "dev.profunktor" %% "redis4cats-effects" % Version
libraryDependencies += "dev.profunktor" %% "redis4cats-log4cats" % Version

where version is 0.10.0-RC2

But when I compile I get:

```scala
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type dev.profunctor.redis4cats.effect.Log[cats.effect.IO]
```

what am I missing here? This is straight from the README here

https://redis4cats.profunktor.dev/

Comment: `import dev.profunktor.redis4cats.effect.Log.NoOp._`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```scala
  implicit val log : Log[IO] = Log.NoOp.instance
```